# How we assingn value to spring form fields from reference data method on loading

Tags: spring, jsp, jakarta-ee, servlets, spring-mvc

I have one spring form name UpdateStock.jsp

```
<form:form........>
 <form:input path="compAmount"/>
 ............
</form:form>
```

My intent is initialize the above spring form text box by some default values from database. So I have form text tag to

```
   <form:input path="compAmount" value=${compamount}/>
```

Here ${compamount} is one of the value returned from referenceData() method.
But the problem is value=${compamount} is invalid.

So I leave it and do the next thing as below:

that is initialize **Object command** object in **reference_Data()** method as below. But it is not working.

```
protected Map reference_Data(HttpServletRequest request, Object command,Errors errors, int page) throws Exception {

   UpdateStockBean bean=new UpdateStockBean();//which is correspond to UpdateStock.jsp page

   bean.setCompAmount(300);//this do not change the value of corresponding field
   command=new Object();
   command=(Object)bean;

}
```

Can you suggest solution!

Comment: When you put any path in form:input, when we render the JSP it calls the getter of that variable which you put in the path. Hope it'll answer your question

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want to some default values for some text fields of your form. If you are using `SimpleFormController` you can simply override the method `protected Object formBackingObject(HttpServletRequest request)` to populate your form with some default data in the fields of your form.

You should not use `protected Map referenceData(HttpServletRequest request)` method for this purpose. Because `referenceData` is used for providing list data for checkboxes or radio buttons. This is nicely explained in [this nice article](http://www.mkyong.com/spring-mvc/spring-mvc-form-handling-example/) of mkyoung.

If you are using `AbstractWizardFormController`, still you have the methods `protected Object formBackingObject(HttpServletRequest request)` and `protected Map referenceData(HttpServletRequest request)`. Because [AbstractWizardFormController](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/api/org/springframework/web/servlet/mvc/AbstractWizardFormController.html) is a subclass of [AbstractFormController](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/api/org/springframework/web/servlet/mvc/AbstractFormController.html), which eventually holds the above mentioned methods. Here is a [sample demonstration](http://www.mkyong.com/spring-mvc/spring-mvc-handling-multipage-forms-with-abstractwizardformcontroller/) of using `AbstractWizardFormController` with form baking object.

Cheers!

Comment: I need AbstractWizardFormController class which doesnot have this method

Comment: Of course AbstractWizardFormController has the methods! see the answer above!

Comment: thanks sir.i have another problem------>how we reference current form object in formBackingObject() method if the object is configured and create new object if form object is not configured

Answer (score 0):

you  can try somethig like this, you are using `Map` Collection:

```
Map yourname = new HashMap(); 
yourname.put("compamount", bean.getCompAmount());
```

So a here ${compamount} is one of the value returned from reference_Data() method.

**I hope help you :)**

Comment: then  <form:input path="compAmount" value=${compamount}/> is possible